# Como excluir linha do datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Populo o `datagridView` assim:

```
dgvProdutosErp.DataSource = produtos; // produtos é uma lista
```

Tento remover da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProdutosErp.Rows)
{
    dgvProdutosErp.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);    
}
```

O seguinte erro ocorre:

> Não é possível remover programaticamente as linhas, a menos que DataGridView seja associado a dados em uma IBindingList com suporte para notificação de alteração e que permita exclusão.

Comment: Você não pode remover o item da `datagridview`, pois está associado ao `dataSource`, você deve excluir a linha em produtos e atualizar o `dgvProdutosErp`, ou não usar o `DataSource` e preencher o `datagridview` na mão mesmo

Comment: Obrigado Marco...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução foi a seguinte:

Populei diferente e consegui excluir.

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<ProdutosModel>(produtos);
                var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
                dgvProdutosErp.DataSource = source;
```

Exclusão:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProdutosErp.Rows)
{
    dgvProdutosErp.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

Comment: tentei usar esse seu código, mas aqui ele está apagando mais de um item ao mesmo tempo. no seu só apaga o item selecionado?